# Syntax error while giving a new user administration permissions in ejabberd.ym

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

For the last couple of hours I have been trying setting **ejabberd** server up. I built ejabberd **from source** becuase the package in ubuntu repository has a bug.
Anyway after building ejabberd from the source, I added my **FQDN** **"s1.noureldin.local**" to my /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml file.

```
.
.
##   - "example.org"
##
hosts:
  - "localhost"
  - "s1.noureldin.local"
##
## route_subdomains: Delegate subdomains to other XMPP servers.
.
.
```

and then I created a **new user**:

```
ejabberdctl register admin1 s1.noureldin.local P@s5W0rd
```

then I tried to connect to my xmpp server and it **worked**!

Now the **PROBLEM** comes when I try to **give that new user administrator permissions**, ejabberd cannot be started any more, and **I always get syntax error in the log**:

```
2016-07-12 12:00:10.733 [info] <0.7.0> Application lager started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:10.977 [info] <0.7.0> Application crypto started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:11.022 [info] <0.7.0> Application sasl started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:11.084 [info] <0.7.0> Application asn1 started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:11.084 [info] <0.7.0> Application public_key started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:11.146 [info] <0.7.0> Application ssl started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:11.171 [info] <0.7.0> Application fast_yaml started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:11.198 [info] <0.7.0> Application fast_tls started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:11.219 [info] <0.7.0> Application fast_xml started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:11.231 [info] <0.7.0> Application stringprep started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:11.245 [info] <0.7.0> Application cache_tab started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:11.687 [info] <0.7.0> Application mnesia started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:14.902 [info] <0.7.0> Application inets started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-07-12 12:00:14.904 [error] <0.37.0>@ejabberd_config:get_plain_terms_file:257 Cannot load //etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml: Syntax error on line 423 at position 3: did not find expected key
```

Here is my ejabberd.yml, you can see all the syntaxes I tried but with no success:

```
.
.
.
max_fsm_queue: 1000

###.   ====================
###'   ACCESS CONTROL LISTS
acl:
  ##
  ## The 'admin' ACL grants administrative privileges to XMPP accounts.
  ## You can put here as many accounts as you want.
  ##
     admin:
       user:
       - "admin1@s1.noureldin.local"
  ######## I TRIED THESE AS WELL ########
  ##     - "admin1":"s1.noureldin.local"
  ##     - "admin1@s1.noureldin.local"
  ##
  ##   user: - "admin1@s1.noureldin.local"
  ##   - user: "admin1@s1.noureldin.local"

  ## Blocked users
  ##
  ## blocked:
  ##   user:
  ##     - "baduser@example.org"
  ##     - "test"

  ## Local users: don't modify this.
  ##
  local:
    user_regexp: ""

  ##
  ## More examples of ACLs
  ##
  ## jabberorg:
.
.
.
```

And when I recomment these lines out, it works again:

```
admin:
   user:
   - "admin1@s1.noureldin.local"
```

Could someone help me to solve that please? I searched online and in ejabberd doc, all peoples used the same syntax I used but that worked with them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the error. **ejabberd.yml** file is **white spaces sensetive**!

and every **sub config MUST have TWO white spaces more that its parent**, so my config will become:

```
acl:
  ##
  ## The 'admin' ACL grants administrative privileges to XMPP accounts.
  ## You can put here as many accounts as you want.
  ##
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin1@s1.noureldin.local"
  ##    - "aleksey@localhost"
  ##
  ## Blocked users
```

Or more clearly:

```
acl:   
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin1@s1.noureldin.local"
```

Comment: That's YAML. Yaml is structured by spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML